# What spyware protection is available for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, anti-spyware

How well protected is Windows 7 from spyware? What free clients are available? Do the clients for Windows Vista work at all with Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 is not fully released yet is it? Therefore I wouldn't think there was any. I might be wrong.

**EDIT**

Strike that here is a [list of antispyware software compatible with windows 7](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2009/01/15/list-of-spyware-protection-software-compatible-with-windows-7/)

Answer (score 3):

Most all programs compatible with Windows Vista (and even XP) are compatible with Windows 7. This would include anti-spyware apps.

These are a few I've used:
- SpyBot (http://www.safer-networking.org/)
- MalwareBytes (http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
- Ad-Aware (http://www.lavasoft.com/)

... and of course there is always [Windows Defender](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx) which is a feature of Windows 7 (as well as Vista)

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Defender](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx)

Free, specifically designed for Windows Vista and 7, built by Microsoft, working fine on my Windows 7 RC.