# How to get a free full anti malware coverage on windows?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, rootkit, anti-spyware, anti-malware

There are many specialized anti malware applications, namely:

- Anti-virus
- Anti-spyware
- Anti-malware
- Anti-rootkit

And so on. What combination of free Windows tools would protect me from any sort of malware?

Comment: Combo? Many of these have been answered before: http://superuser.com/questions/1334/what-spyware-protection-is-available-for-windows-7 , http://superuser.com/questions/14750/which-rootkit-cleaner-for-window-xp-do-you-recommend , http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows , http://superuser.com/questions/249/free-anti-spyware-programs-for-windows

Comment: Click on the tags you have assigned to this question and you will find many similar questions and information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 or rather 7 if you are extra paranoid:

1. User your Brain.exe carefully!
2. [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.com) with [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722) and [AdBlock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865)
3. [Avira AntiVir Personal](http://www.free-av.com/en/products/index.html) (You don't need German to read numbers, [Antivirus benchmark](http://j.mp/7NdJiE), or go directly [to the source](http://www.av-comparatives.org/))
4. [Comodo Personal Firewall](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/)

If you want to be extra, extra, extra paranoid, throw in:

7. [Spybot-S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html)
8. [HiJackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/)
9. [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)

I couldn't care less about malware, keyloggers and whatnot with this setup.

Comment: Brain.exe is really tempermental though. Sometimes it can do the job of all of them, but for some people it just doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

**[Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)**, because it is just so much wiser to prevent infections from happening rather than cleaning up when the damage is done (and save your system resources for things that really matter).

Comment: Sandboxie doesn't support 64-bit OS

Comment: you don't say, i suggest you edit your question (and tags) accordingly then. :)

Answer (score 0):

- [Windows defender](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx) for spyware
- [AVG](http://www.avg.com) for the others

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how advanced/paranoid you are, when you simply *must* do something that could potentially harm your PC, don't underestimate the value of virtualization technology. As long as you keep your virtual machines as airtight as possible (no shared folders, etc.) there is little if any worry of your host OS being compromised.

I've used Sun's VirtualBox for this and it is honestly the best anti-malware tool in my arsenal. When your VM is infected (which shouldn't be too often with judicious application of Brain.exe, as pointed out by a previous answer), simply delete the associated hard drive image and start over with a backup one.

Answer (score -1):

Having your computer's network interface removed entirely should do the job. Also don't plug in any external storage devices or disks and make sure to have your RAM cleared regularly along with frequent file shreddings and drive formattings
Your files and user experience are now safe as safe can be.

Otherwise [Tin-Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_Hat_Linux) is for you, in all its super safe glory.

But really:

1. Remove all software you don't need
2. Use firefox or opera as your internet browser
3. Disable both Java and Javascript in the preferences
4. Ensure you have a decent firewall (like AVG)
5. [Spybot search and destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html) is really good for protecting against infection through protection.
6. If your router or modem has security settings, enable them
7. Disable windows file sharing
8. Block ports, like NetBios (which can be used in exploits)
9. [Disable unnecessary windows services](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,1697,1786006,00.asp) (like remote registry edditing)
10. Finally, if you are really paranoid, run a Nessus scan to see what vulnerabilties exist on your system. Then fix them up.

Hope this helps, and god-speed